# Knex query error "pollers.description\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

So I have 2 tables(pollers and errors) I am trying to join on where pollers.id = errors.poller_id and then count the number of errors a poller has using the pollers.id. I used:

```
 knex.raw(`select poller_name, description, count(pollers.id) as "poller_errors" 
from pollers
inner join 
errors on pollers.id = errors.poller_id 
group by poller_name`)
```

it came up with an error "pollers.description\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: `group by poller_name, description`. That's just like a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear.  As a general rule, the unaggregated columns in the `select` need to be in the `group by`.  So just put them there:

```
select poller_name, description, count(pollers.id) as "poller_errors"
from pollers inner join
     errors
     on pollers.id = errors.poller_id
group by poller_name, description;
```

That said, there is one important exception to this, which goes by the fancy name of "functional dependency".  You can aggregate by a primary or unique key and use other columns from the same table.  I am guessing that `pollers.id` is a unique key.  If so, you could write this as:

```
select p.poller_name, p.description, count(*) as poller_errors
from pollers p inner join
     errors e
     on p.id = e.poller_id
group by p.id;
```

Note the other changes to this code:

- All column references are qualified, so it is clear to you, the compiler, and anyone who reads the code where they are coming from.
- Table abbreviations are used for the aliases.
- The double quotes are removed from the column aliases.  Don't get in the habit of escaping column references.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I appreciate you. It worked!